# Show Label by default for Map in JvectorMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I am using JVectorMap for my work. I need to show the labels of the countries by default. It currently shows when you hover over a country. But how to get it show by default while the user opens the page.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19123531/1324929